Long vs Short Volatility Skew
This question is purely on the structure or maybe even jargon of being long or short volatility skew. Realistically, we do know that when we are long skew, we are long an OTM put and short an OTM call, generally speaking.
But why is that?
Thinking in terms of skew, you are:

Negative skew if your vol skew is downward sloping
Flat skew if your vol skew is flat
Positive skew if your vol skew is downward sloping

However, longing an OTM put and shorting an OTM call has the effect of going long vol at lower strikes and going short vol at the higher strike, betting that vol skew is going more negative effectively.
My question is what exactly does it mean when we buy skew or sell skew, and have I got the graphical relationship wrong?

My question is what exactly does it mean when we buy skew or sell skew, and have I got the graphical relationship wrong?
To go long skew simply means that the negative skew becomes "more downward sloping" and thus you go long (short) OTM puts (calls) that represent the left (right) ends of the skew to profit from the steepening. To illustrate with a Figure:

Also, this link might be useful: Does skew flatten with a decline in volatility?

Thanks for this :)
